# How can I make up for it?

Tags: sankalpa

I started a 11 days 11 times Hanuman Chalisa Sankalpa and on the 5th day I couldn't control my urges and gave up to masturbation and also during this period I failed to control the urges of smoking. Today is my 6th day, What should I do? Will he forgive me and how can I make up to him?

Comment: Assess what damage it is doing to you. Imagine the damage in detail. Internalise the damage vs the rewards into the core of your being or mind. Start again. Do not give up till you succeed. This question being personal advice in nature will be deleted. Until then!

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Comment: It takes insight to realise that certain mental traits are the result of a kind of need for variety, stemming from dissatisfaction, stemming from the chemicals for hyperactivity. By constant practice you remove that disturbing layer. Try forsaking nonveg at start or permanently. It reduces hyperactivity hormones. Our scriptures did not have chemical analysers, but they were scientific due to accumulation of centuries of observation, discussion , experiment and divine visions

Answer (score 1):

No direct mention of your problems in any scripture but a line of hope from hanuman chalisa

---

> जो सत बार पाठ कर कोई, छूटहि बंदि महा सुख होई॥38॥
>
> अर्थ-जो कोई इस हनुमान चालीसा का सौ बार पाठ करेगा वह सब बंधनों से छूट जाएगा और उसे परमानन्द मिलेगा । जो साधक पूर्ण श्रद्धा, आस्था एवं लगन के साथ हनुमान चालीसा का पाठ सौ बार करता है उसे जीवन मृत्यु के बंधन से मुक्त मिलती हैं इसमे लेश मात्र भी संशय नहीं है।